# Can I close terminal while waiting waiting for App Store Connect to finish processing the new build?

Tags: fastlane

I am using fastlane to build and upload ipa to iTC with submitting for review flag true.

when complete uploading,iTC need time to process the ipa.Normally,it takes one hour.Then Fastlane will request submitting for review.

My question is,when fastlane continuously output 'Waiting for App Store Connect to finish processing the new build',can I close the terminal,or I must keep it alive?

Here is my fastlane action

```
lane :build_app_store do
    build_app(
        export_method: "app-store",
        export_options: PROVISION_PROFILE_APP_STORE,
        output_directory: OUTPUT_DIRECTORY,
        silent: true,
        clean: true,)
    appstore(force: true, # Skip HTMl report verification
        skip_screenshots:true, 
        skip_metadata: true,
        app_identifier: "com.app.cn",
        submit_for_review: false,
        phased_release: true)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can close the terminal and you can use this action to be notified when the process is finished: https://github.com/fastlane/watchbuild

It's not a replacement for `deliver` or `pilot`, it's just a utility which triggers a notification when the process is finished

Comment: Even if I want to submit app automatically?